# using qsort function to sort a struct

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, struct, qsort

so I need to use qsort() to sort an array that contains a structure

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

// =========
struct pair
{
    int encounters;
};// pair{}

int compaireEncounters(const void*, const void*);

int main()
{
    struct pair* working[5];
    working[0]->encounters = 10;
    working[1]->encounters = 3;
    working[2]->encounters = 1;

    qsort(working, 5, sizeof(struct pair), compareEncounters);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 3)
    {
        printf("%d \n", working[i]->encounters)
        i++;
    }

}

int compaireEncounters(const void* av, const void* bv)
{
    int a = ((struct pair*)av)->encounters;
    int b = ((struct pair*)bc)->encounters;
    return(a > b);
}
```

I am trying to get the output:

```sh
1 
3
10
```

but instead i get a segmentation fault core dump.

What is the issue here?

Comment: Why did you declare an array of pointers to the type struct pair instead of objects of the same type?!

Comment: I'm unsure of what you are asking in the question as i am still new to C. however i need to copy data from a hash table into an array i called working

Comment: What is unclea?. All is clear. You declared an array of pointers  struct pair* working[5]; instead of an array of objects of the type struct pair like struct pair working[5]; Why? And moreover you are calling qsort as if you have an array of objects instead of an array of pointers qsort(working, 5, sizeof(struct pair), compareEncounters); that is you are using sizeof( struct pair ) instead of sizeof( struct pair * ).

Comment: I apologize as I didn't know any better, what is the correct way to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must assign pointers to valid buffers before dereferencing pointers.

In this case, `working` should be an array of the structure, not an array of pointers.

Also don't forget to initialize all elements to be sorted.

There are also more mistakes in your code:

- `qsort` is used without including proper header (`stdlib.h`)
- Undeclared `compareEncounters` is used in the `main` function.
- A semicolon is missing after the `printf()` statement.
- Undeclared `bc` is used in the `compaireEncounters` function.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// =========
struct pair{
    int encounters;
};// pair{}

int compaireEncounters(const void* , const void*);

int main() {
    struct pair working[5];
    working[0].encounters = 10;
    working[1].encounters = 3;
    working[2].encounters = 1;
    working[3].encounters = 334;
    working[4].encounters = 42;

    qsort(working, 5, sizeof(struct pair), compaireEncounters);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 3) {
        printf("%d \n", working[i].encounters);
        i++;
    }

}

int compaireEncounters(const void* av, const void* bv){
    int a = ((struct pair*)av)->encounters;
    int b = ((struct pair*)bv)->encounters;
    return(a > b);
}
```

If you want to work with an array of pointers,

- Allocate buffers and assign them before dereferencing.
- Fix the element size for `qsort()`.
- Fix `compaireEncounters` to compare the pointers to the structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// =========
struct pair{
    int encounters;
};// pair{}

int compaireEncounters(const void* , const void*);

int main() {
    struct pair* working[5];
    working[0] = malloc(sizeof(*working[0])); working[0]->encounters = 10;
    working[1] = malloc(sizeof(*working[1])); working[1]->encounters = 3;
    working[2] = malloc(sizeof(*working[2])); working[2]->encounters = 1;
    working[3] = malloc(sizeof(*working[3])); working[3]->encounters = 334;
    working[4] = malloc(sizeof(*working[4])); working[4]->encounters = 42;

    qsort(working, 5, sizeof(*working), compaireEncounters);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 3) {
        printf("%d \n", working[i]->encounters);
        i++;
    }

}

int compaireEncounters(const void* av, const void* bv){
    int a = (*(struct pair**)av)->encounters;
    int b = (*(struct pair**)bv)->encounters;
    return(a > b);
}
```

Comment: is there any way to get it to work with the struct pair*? this is my MRE example and only utilizing a snippet of the code and i was transferring data from a hash table into this array

Comment: @itsMe Yes, added that.

Comment: your efforts are ensued by utmost appreciation. your solution has indeed solved the issue(s) that i have encountered.

Comment: The `qsort` comparison function should be returning a value less then, equal, or greater than 0, which the current comparison function doesn't do.